# How to attach fragment to Navigationview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigationview

I am using NaivgationView in my app, when i select item from drawer,the view of my fragment which i set is not displaying. i also added toast it shows while i select that item can any one help me with this ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
       {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.home:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inbox Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.be_the_donor:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stared Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        RegisterDonor frag = new RegisterDonor();

                        // update the main content by replacing fragments
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .replace(R.id.frame_container, frag)
                                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.search_donor:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Send Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.tools:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Drafts Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });

        // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Fragment

```
public class RegisterDonor extends Fragment{



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_donor, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.dayshift.bloodfinder.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

register_donor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_donor_username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Enter Name"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/mobileWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_donor_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Enter Mobile"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/register_donor_bloodgroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Material Design Spinner"
        android:textColorHint="#05ab9a"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />

    <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/register_donor_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Material Design Spinner"
        android:textColorHint="#05ab9a"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/register_donor_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="">
        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Pls show your RegisterDonor fragment.

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal check

Comment: Are you sure that id 'be_the_donor' is correct?

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah it is correct

Comment: are you importing android.support.v4.app.Fragment; ? or android.app.Fragment?

Comment: android.app.Fragment

Comment: okay, change to android.support.v4.app.Fragment and see if it works.

Comment: it dint work i tried that too

Comment: Why are you not using the support FragmentManager?

Comment: cricket_007 might be correct. Please try using FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

Comment: Your code looks fine otherwise, so add your xml files

Comment: xml files are same as we create new project with selecting navigation drawer activity in studio

Comment: That's great. Please show them so we can try to reproduce your problem

Comment: @cricket_007 tell me which xml ?

Comment: `activity_main.xml`? `content_main.xml`? Your Fragment... `register_donor.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app bar occupies the entire screen.

```
   <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
```

Change the app bar to wrap content on the height

Answer (score 0):

In activity_main_drawer write your item with id and title after that in mainactivity in method onNavigationItemSelected for your id declare your fragment and commit

Answer (score -1):

You are telling that the Toasts are showing up but not the fragment so the problem might be the **FragmentManager**

check you import of fragmentManager which should be

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

and should not be

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

And your fragment transaction should be like this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
RegisterDonor frag = new RegisterDonor();

fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, frag , "")
                            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
```

hope this will help you!

Comment: still same issue

Comment: try initialize your DrawerLayout with its corresponding id before the listener

Comment: also check for the import of Fragment in your RegisterDonor

Answer (score -1):

Try this way i guess it works fine :

```
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.be_the_donor:
                    Fragment registerDonor = new RegisterDonor();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, registerDonor);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
```